# Using a USB 3.0 hub to connect to two cameras

Tags: usb-3

I want to connect two USB camers to my laptop. I have in my laptop USB 2.0 adapter so only one camera can work; so I want to know if I connect a USB 3.0 hub to my laptop USB 2.0 adapter will that  make my laptop speed up transfers to run two camera with out any problems ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm reading this right, then you are doing this:

USB Camera1 & USB Camera2------>USB 3.0 Hub----->USB 2.0 Port on laptop.

Connecting a USB 3.0 hub to a USB 2.0 port on your computer will not make the cameras run at USB 3.0.  Your laptop only has capability for USB 2.0, therefore your USB 3.0 devices/hub would pass into your USB 2.0 port and be slowed to 2.0 speed.

The USB 3.0 hub will still work, albeit at USB 2.0 speeds.

Comment: if i used this device can that chang any thang http://www.amazon.com/dp/B0046TQ21M/?tag=stackoverfl08-20 ?

Comment: @shar assuming your laptop has an expresscard slot, yes, that should give you USB 3 speeds